# Find all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists 2x2 integer matrix $A$ (not being an identity matrix) such that $A^n=I_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists $\mbox{2x2}$ integer matrix $A$ (not being an identity matrix) such that $A^n=I_2$.

Any hint please?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534198/a-2-times-2-matrix-a-such-that-an-is-the-identity-matrix?rq=1

Comment: Try thinking of what matrix multiplication does to the plane, and remembering that matrix multiplication is function composition.  So if a matrix $A$ rotates the plane by $90^\circ$, $A^4$ rotates by $360^\circ$, which is the identity.

Comment: @Terra it's not a duplicate...

Comment: I see that now. You want only integers. That may change the answer substantially. Apologies.

Comment: @Terra, no worries

Comment: Why is anyone asking you this? Look up the modular group. You are also considering determinants $-1,$ not sure how much worse that makes it. You can get $n=2,3,4,6,$ do not currently think you can get 12.

Comment: I believe all multiplies of $4$ work. Take rotation matrix (90 deg)

Comment: Yes, but that actually satisfies $A^4 = I.$ If you are not going to use the smallest $n$ that works, then you can get $2n,3n,4n,6n.$ I see, the only restriction is $A \neq I.$ Again, where did you get the problem?

Comment: It's a test task for Phd in mathematics candidates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hints.*

1. If $A^n=I$, what are the possible eigenvalues of $A$ over $\mathbb C$?
2. In view of (1), since the trace of $A$ must be an integer, and any non real eigenvalues of $A$ must occur in conjugate pairs, can you narrow down the possible eigenvalues of $A$?
3. The candidate eigenvalues in (2) are realisable by integer matrices. Why? (Think companion matrix.) Now, what can you say about $n$?

Comment: 1) n-th roots of unity?

Comment: @luka5z Yes. So, there are two possibilities: 2(a) the eigenvalues belong to the set $\{-1,1\}$, or 2(b) the spectrum must be in the form of $\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$ such that $\sin\theta\ne0$. In the latter case, since $2\cos\theta$ (the trace of $A$) has to be an integer, you can say something more...